# Tracking non fatal error in iOS app

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to ask about some tips how to track non fatal errors and bugs in my app. I am currently using Crashlytics to track fatal errors and I could also use it to rack non fatal ones but I was wondering if there is something better for this purpose. I am mainly interested in tracking issues with requests and with obtaining data from server.

Comment: You really need to tell us what you've tried.  Otherwise people are going to post the bleeding obvious, or just not bother at all.  Eg, are you interested in suggestions such as lots of logging, or using the standard debugging tools, such as breakpoints and stepping through code and examining values as you step through.  Or are these things that you're already well versed in?

Comment: sorry, i was not specific enough,I am looking for way to track this issues remotely. Same way you track  crashes on user devices using  Fabric, hockey app etc. I was just wondering if there is specific framework to track non fatal issues where I would specify criteria when to log the issue and send the log back to me.